# Laravel - open popup/modal for each post from list

Tags: laravel

I have a page with a list of blog posts.
What would be the best way to open the post content on the same page in a modal, without redirecting to the single post page?

What I thought it's to make it in vanilla JS, to have an event on each post, have the data for all the posts in some array or each inside an attribute and when the event is triggered, fill the data for that post in the modal and show it. Maybe I can use AlpineJS for this.
Seems rudimentary to have it in vanilla, is there a better way to do it?
I also thought about Livewire, but I'm afraid it will be slow, have looked on some videos on YT, and when the button was clicked, it was visible when the data was filling in, looked slow.
Have thought also to make API calls, but I'd have to make the authentication work on that specific route, which would complicate it too much I guess, since it's going to be used just for this page.

What are your thoughts, how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

All your suggestions would work. Just depends on what you prefer and are able to implement. Also, think around opening the Post content in a modal, how much data do you want to load in the modal? Such questions will assist in you deciding the best way to design the post page.

Comment: It will have some data about the author, a logo and a small description. It's actually a Task, not a post, it will have some tags too, which come from the relationships of this model. I am able to implement anything, have not talked to the client yet, that's why I want to have some choices to present to him.